# Spin Up Instances using OpsWorks Instance AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have a OpsWorks stack where an instance is running. For some reason, I want to run a similar instance inside a different VPC. So, I created a new OpsWorks stack that uses the VPC. Baked an AMI using the old instance. I spun up an instance on the new stack. But, the problem is that setup never completes. It runs in 'running_setup' status forever. Since I don't want to configure anything on the new instance as it uses an AMI that has everything I want, the run_list (recipes list) is empty.

I ssh'ed into the server. I found that an aws-opsworks agent is already running. I manually killed the agent. But, no luck.

I'm running the new instance inside an OpsWorks stack because I might need to run some new recipes in future.

So, I'm looking for a way to spin up instance in OpsWorks using an AMI where OpsWorks agent is already installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that instance getting created in a Private subnet?

Comment: @error2007s No, both instances are in public subnet with public ips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you create a AMI running Opsworks you need to make sure there are certain steps that needs to be followed before you hit create AMI button in AWS.

Check this guide and make sure you followed all the steps mentioned before you created that AMI, as you mentioned Opsworks agent is already running this should not happen so you are definitely missing one of or all the steps mentioned in this guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html#workinginstances-custom-ami-create-opsworks